# Angular ng-class multiple condition

Tags: angularjs

I would like to apply multiple class:

`<span ng-class="false ? 'class-right' : 'class-left', 'class-middle': true">`

the `'class-middle': true` is the error part.

What is the right syntax to this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an object like that :

```
<span ng-class="{'class-left': aBoolean, 'class-middle': aSetOrUndefinedOrNullVar, 'class-right': aFunctionReturningABoolean}">
```

If a class is always at true, just add it as a normal class in your `class="my-class"` attribute.